# Database child doesn't accept value of a variable?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

I'm trying to make app to save locations of a users 
when the user update locations 
the location will be saved in the database 
i'm trying to get value from another activity and and it is String 
and I put the value in a variable and put it in the child(the variable)
but the app doesn't work because of this 
when i put child("whatever") it works 
when i put child(variable)doesn't work
why ?

```
inner class myLocarionListenr: LocationListener {
        val us4 = intent.getStringExtra("user")

        constructor(){
            myLocation = Location("me")
            myLocation!!.longitude = 0.0
            myLocation!!.latitude =0.0
        }
        override fun onLocationChanged(location: Location?) {
            myLocation = location
            val longtude = myLocation!!.longitude
            val latetude = myLocation!!.latitude


            val myDatabase:DatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("user's location")
            val ulocation = com.example.firebase.location(us4,longtude,latetude)


            myDatabase.child(us4).child("locations").setValue(ulocation).addOnCompleteListener {
                Toast.makeText(this@MapsActivity,"location saved",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
```

child(us4) makes the app crash

Comment: post the error log please

Comment: the application crash and sends me back to the main activity

Comment: if i change the child(us4) to child("any String") it will work

Comment: check your logcat. There must be have error message there.

Comment: com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Invalid Firebase Database path: leti@gmail.com. Firebase Database paths must not contain '.', '#', '$', '[', or ']'

Comment: i solved it 
the problem was with th @ of the email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the error:

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Invalid Firebase Database path: leti@gmail.com. Firebase Database paths must not contain '.', '#', '$', '[', or ']'

You have an email in your path and since email contains the character `@`, then you got the above error. You need to change the email to a `userId` that will let you identify a user easily.

Comment: No problem Goodluck!